# Mary TTS voice variation

Tags: marytts

I am using `mary tts 5.1` and the voice `dfki-prudence` (English female).

This voice variation is not working (in emotions like happy, sad, angry, etc.). But this emotion is working in the voice `cmu-slt-hsmm`(English female).  Voice `dfki-prudence`(English female) is good.

How do I make changes in the **dfki-prudence (English female) voice** variation? Anyone know?

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: yes I am tried.  from this link "https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki/Local-MaryTTS-Server-Installation".

Comment: Where did you get stuck in the installation process? How are you planning to use the library? And why you say you were unsuccessful downloading the code, there is a big [download] button on the home page of the repo.

Comment: build mary tts in this step i am stucked because getting below error.            
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-

Comment: I am installed the mary tts 5.1 .and I am installed dfki-prudence(English Female)voice .voice variation(in emotionml like  happy, angry,sad) is not working for this voice.but voice variation working for cmu-slt-hsmm(English female)voice.

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with this framework. Though I recommend you to edit your question, maybe some one else understands it.

Answer (score 0):

The `dfki-prudence` voice does not support the expressive styles.

Only `dfki-pavoque-styles` has this feature.

It is the answer from [official github](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/issues/541#issuecomment-224250567).